# Wait until process is killed to launch another process

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian, sh

I have no experience writting sh/bash script for linux, I want to check if a process is running. If the process is running then wait, when the process is killed then execute another proccess, something like this (pseudo-code):

```
while main_process.run = True {
    do_nothing;
}
execute new_process
```

How can I do this in a small script.sh? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your shell did start the process you are waiting for, then:

```
wait <process id>
execute_new_process
```